# angular app works locally but on live server only display list of files

Tags: angular

I am facing this problem and I have searched a lot about it but it's not fixed. The problem is when I build my angular app and run it locally it works, but when I upload it on the live server and run, then it only displays the index of files (see uploaded image). Is this the problem of my server or build.
I have uploaded the build on `myapp` folder and when I run the URL like https://example.net/myapp it displays the lists of Html, js, fonts files only. I have also changed base href in index.html file like this `<base href="/myapp/">`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with my server, I have fixed the problem with `.htacess` file, by putting `DirectoryIndex index.html` in it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what server you are running but for apache tomcat for example when you put your app (static files + index.html ) to `/var/www/html/` so you have to make the basehref as `<base href="/">`, 
if in `/var/www/html/example/` so `<base href="/example/">` ...

Comment: after you build you apps you must have dist folder with index.html and some css and javascript files you must put them in html/ folder you did it ?

Comment: I have uploaded all the files to my server(apache) including index.html from dist folder to public_html/myapp and changed the base to href="/myapp/" but still the problem is not fixed. I have visited the URL like https://example.net/myapp it won't work, but when I visit https://example.net/myapp/index.html then the app loads perfectly. I just don't understand that the problem is the server is not reading index.html automatically or angular does not load default route.

Comment: There is a problem with my server, I have fixed the problem with .htacess file, by putting "DirectoryIndex index.html" in it.